# PIC16F18877: Using I2C to read sensor (LSM9DS0) value

Tags: pic, i2c

Every time I go through the code step-by-step in debug mode, I end up having the same value in `SSP1BUF` even after changing the orientation of the sensor.

1. I send slave address with write bit.
2. I send slave sub address.
3. I send slave address with read bit.
4. Output the received value in PORTB.

I am probably going wrong somewhere in the last 10-15 lines of code. Please have a look.
Thanks!

```
#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 32000000

void main(void)
{

    TRISC = 0x18; // Set RC3(SCL) and RC4(SDA) as inputs.
    ANSELC = 0;   // In debug mode I can see RC3 and RC4 high after stepping into
                  // this line of code, so I know SDA and SCL are properly pulled
                  // high.
    TRISB = 0;    // Saving received I2C data in PORTB.
    ANSELB = 0;   // After this step the PORTB is filled with the last  
                  // SSPBUF data (0X3D), I find this weird 

 RC3PPS = 0X14;   // 
 RC4PPS = 0X15;   // Setting RC3 and RC4 as SCL and SDA pins
 SSP1CON1 = 0X28; // SSPEN - 1, SSPM - 1000
 SSP1ADD = 0X03; // clock frequency 31.25 kHz
 SSP1STAT = 0X80; // SMP - 1

 // First write with slave address
 SSP1CON2bits.SEN = 1;  // Start I2C

 while (SSP1CON2bits.SEN == 1); // Wait for "START" to finish
 PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;           
 SSP1BUF = 0X3C;                // LSM9DS0 Accelerometer address(with write bit)
                                // Page 33 in LSM9DS0 data sheet
 while((PIR3bits.SSP1IF == 0) && (SSP1STATbits.BF == 1) && (SSP1STATbits.R_nW == 1));
 PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;           // Wait for transmission to complete 

 // Slave sub Address
 SSP1BUF = 0X2C;                // sub-address of Z-axis acceleration data 
                                // register, first 8 bits
 while((PIR3bits.SSP1IF == 0) && (SSP1STATbits.BF == 1) && (SSP1STATbits.R_nW == 1));
 PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;           // Wait for transmission to complete

 // Repeated Start
 SSP1CON2bits.RSEN = 1;        // Repeated Start so that I can start reading the  
                               // above Z axis data
 while (SSP1CON2bits.RSEN == 1);/* Wait if Transmit in progress */
 PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
 SSP1BUF = 0X3D;               // LSM9DS0 Accelerometer address(with read bit)
                                // Page 33 in LSM9DS0 data sheet
 while((PIR3bits.SSP1IF == 0) && (SSP1STATbits.BF == 1) && (SSP1STATbits.R_nW == 1));
 PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;          // Wait for transmission to complete

 SSP1CON2bits.RCEN = 1;        // Enable receive in I2C
 //while ( SSP1CON2bits.RCEN == 1);
 while(SSP1STATbits.BF == 0);
 PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;
 PORTB = SSP1BUF;              

 SSP1CON2bits.ACKDT = 1;
 SSP1CON2bits.ACKEN = 1;
 while( SSP1CON2bits.ACKEN == 1);
 PIR3bits.SSP1IF = 0;

 SSP1CON2bits.PEN = 1;
 while(1);


}
```

Comment: Hi, (a) While you are waiting for someone to review your code, have you got either an oscilloscope or logic analyser? Then you could run the code (not debug step-by-step), capture the I2C bus activity, check whether the master and slave activity is as expected - and, if not, see where the behaviour is wrong. That will help progress your troubleshooting. (b) Are you using known-good I2C code copied from a reputable source (if so, please add a link), or are you writing it from scratch yourself? (c) As a new user, please read the [tour] and [help] to learn about the site rules. Welcome :-)

Comment: (a) I don't have oscilloscope or logic analyzer, I'll buy an analyzer (b) I am trying to write the code from scratch (c) Sure! Let me know if I went wrong somewhere in my post/ question.

Comment: (a) Good plan. Note that an 'scope is more generally more expensive, but can show subtle problems on an I2C bus, which a logic analyser can't show. If you are *sure* your I2C bus has correct wiring and pull-ups, then a logic analyser *might* be all you need. (b) Less-good plan (IMHO). I don't have time to research my old PIC16 I2C notes now, but I would suggest you start with known-good code, check it works, and then modify it, or at least compare it to yours. Starting with a simpler I2C device might be a good idea. (c) Just pointing you to info - no problems with the question :-) Good luck!

Comment: (b) There's code present over here -http://www.8051projects.net/wiki/I2C_Implementation_on_PIC, and I think my code has the same structure still I don't get different values on for different orientations of my IMU (LSM9DS0).

Answer (score 1):

Your code structure is off and you are ignoring things like ACK.

Here is what the datasheet states the correct structure is.

1. The user generates a Start condition by setting
   the SEN bit of the SSPxCON2 register.
2. SSPxIF is set by hardware on completion of the
   Start.
3. SSPxIF is cleared by software.
4. User writes SSPxBUF with the slave address to
   transmit and the R/W bit set.
5. Address is shifted out the SDA pin until all eight
   bits are transmitted. Transmission begins as
   soon as SSPxBUF is written to.
6. The MSSP module shifts in the ACK bit from the
   slave device and writes its value into the
   ACKSTAT bit of the SSPxCON2 register.
7. The MSSP module generates an interrupt at the
   end of the ninth clock cycle by setting the
   SSPxIF bit.
8. User sets the RCEN bit of the SSPxCON2
   register and the master clocks in a byte from the
   slave.
9. After the eighth falling edge of SCL, SSPxIF and
   BF are set.
10. Master clears SSPxIF and reads the received
    byte from SSPxBUF, clears BF.
11. Master sets ACK value sent to slave in ACKDT
    bit of the SSPxCON2 register and initiates the
    ACK by setting the ACKEN bit.
12. Master’s ACK is clocked out to the slave and
    SSPxIF is set.
13. User clears SSPxIF.
14. Steps 8-13 are repeated for each received byte
    from the slave.
15. Master sends a not ACK or Stop to end
    communication.